# SQL query to retrieve the details of all employees whose job role does not contain vowels in it?

Tags: sql

Basically, I know that each and every word has atleast one vowel in it. But suppose I'm having a employee table which has its attributes like name, id, job role and joining date;
Suppose the job role column has 4 job roles which contains the values in SHORTCUT like mgr means Manager , hr means hiring manager, sd means software developer, se means software engineer. But in the table it is stored as( mgr , hr, sd , se).
QUESTION
So I need to retrieve the details of employees whose job role does not contain  vowels What is the query to solve this question.
I should get the details of all employees except the employees whose job role is se as 'e' is a vowel
please write the query using INSTR() function.
my query is

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE INSTR(JOBROLE , 'A',1,1)=0 AND INSTR(JOBROLE, 'E',1,1)=0 AND INSTR(JOBROLE,'I',1,1)=0 AND INSTR( JOBROLE, 'O',1,1)=0 AND INSTR(JOBROLE , 'U',1,1)=0;**
 AND THE SECOND SOLUTION I WRITTEN IS :**QUERY 2
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE NOT (INSTR(JOBROLE , 'A',1,1)!=0 OR INSTR(JOBROLE, 'E',1,1)!=0 OR INSTR(JOBROLE,'I',1,1)!=0 OR INSTR(JOBROLE, 'O',1,1)!=0 OR INSTR(JOBROLE , 'U',1,1)!=0);
```

Which query gives the desired output and why please explain?
I tried this queries

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE INSTR(JOBROLE , 'A',1,1)=0 AND INSTR(JOBROLE, 'E',1,1)=0 AND INSTR(JOBROLE,'I',1,1)=0 AND INSTR( JOBROLE, 'O',1,1)=0 AND INSTR(JOBROLE , 'U',1,1)=0;
QUERY 2
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE NOT (INSTR(JOBROLE , 'A',1,1)!=0 OR INSTR(JOBROLE, 'E',1,1)!=0 OR INSTR(JOBROLE,'I',1,1)!=0 OR INSTR(JOBROLE, 'O',1,1)!=0 OR INSTR(JOBROLE , 'U',1,1)!=0);
```

but I didn't find any such table to solve my problem and I think query 1 is correct as per my knowledge.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You are using product specific functions.)

Answer (score 0):

INSTR is not a SQL function It is specific to Oracle. You must use POSITION in standard SQL
As an example :

```
WHERE POSITION('A' IN JOB)=0 AND POSITION('E' IN JOB)=0 AND ...
```

Another way is to use the SIMILAR operator which is a super like with some extension like regular expressions. As an example :

```
WHERE JOB NOT SIMILAR TO '%(A|E|I|O|U|Y)%'
```

Some RDBMS have LIKE extensions like Microsoft SQL Server (the one used for StackOverflow...) :

```
WHERE JOB NOT LIKE '%[AEIOUY]%'
```

Comment: What you have written I got it but can you please tell me about my queries which I have written by using instr() are they correct

Comment: INSTR does not exists in the ISO standard SQL language. The correct function is POSITION. You do not mention the RDBMS you use and just tag SQL... So in plain standard ISO SQL the function is POSITION not INSTR which is specific to Oracle Database I think....